# Elixir custom task does not show up on "mix help"

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Is the following code not enough to list a custom task on `mix help`?

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.Start do
  use Mix.Task

  @shortdoc "Starts [App]"
  def run(_) do
    IO.puts("Starting [App]...")
  end
end
```

I thought that the decorator [@shortdoc](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/basics/mix-tasks/#mix-tasks-in-action) was enough to list my custom task on `mix help` but I recompile my code and my custom task is not being listed on `mix help`.

Answer (score 8):

In trying it out myself I had to add both a `@moduledoc` and a `@shortdoc`. Then I had to run `mix compile` to get the task on the list in `mix help`.

Comment: yep: this is the way to refresh the list.

Comment: Here is the code filtering out those having no `@moduledoc`: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.12.2/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/help.ex#L117-L119